# A connection between the Bell numbers and Bell polynomial

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, inequalities

Let $B(n,x) = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\brace k}x^k$ be the Bell polynomials and $B_n = B(n,1)$ be the Bell numbers.

I recently proved a nice relation between the two:
$$
B(n,x)^{1/n}/x \ge B_{n/x}^{x/n},
$$
for integers $n,x\ge 1$.
Here we used the generalization of the Bell numbers to real indicies: $B_z = \frac{1}{e}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^z}{k!}$.
I wonder if this is a known result?

I also conjecture a matching upper bound
$$
B(n,x)^{1/n}/x \le B_{n/x+1}^{1/(n/x+1)}.
$$

I have checked this numerically, but not been able to prove it. I tried using an exponential-generating function bound on $B(n,x)$, but that appears to not be strong enough.

I wonder if this is a known result as well?
I read [the article Berend and Tassa](https://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/%7Epms/files/30.2/Article/30.2.1.pdf), but there doesn't appear to be anything of this kind.

Alternatively, am I missing a simple proof?

Since $B(n,x)$ is also the $n$th raw moment of a Poisson variable with mean $x$, such a result would tie those moments in a simple, uniform way to the Bell numbers.